# Shall I set an empty string computed string attribute for Terraform resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

context: I'm adding a new resource to TF Provider.

I've got an API that optionally return a string attribute so I represent it as:

```
"foo": {
  Type:        schema.TypeString,
  Computed:    true,
  Optional:    true,
},
```

Question: if an API returns value not set / empty string for `response.foo`, shall I still set an empty string for `foo` attribute or I shouldn't set any value instead (e.g., `null`)?
in my resource schema.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Hello! I'm the same person who wrote the answer you included in your screenshot.)

If both approaches -- returning `null` or returning an empty string -- were equally viable from a technical standpoint then I would typically prefer to use `null` to represent the absence of a value, since that is clearly distinct from an empty string which for some situations would otherwise be a valid present value for the attribute.

However, since it seems like you are using the old SDK ("SDKv2") here, you will probably be constrained from a technical standpoint: SDKv2 was designed for Terraform v0.11 and earlier and so it predates the idea of attributes being `null` and so there is no way in its API to specify that. You may be able to "trick" the SDK into *effectively* returning `null` by not calling `d.Set("foo", ...)` at all in your `Create` function, but there is no API provided to *unset* an attribute and so once you've set it to something non-null there would typically be no way to get it to go back to being `null` again.

Given that, I'd suggest it better to be consistent and always use `""` when using the old SDK, because that way users of the provider won't have to deal with the inconsistency of the value sometimes being `null` and sometimes being `""` in this case.

When using the modern [Terraform Plugin Framework](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/framework) this limitation doesn't apply, because that framework was designed with the modern Terraform language in mind. You aren't using that framework and so this part of the answer probably won't help you right now, but I'm mentioning it just in case someone else finds this answer in future who might already be using or be considering use of the new framework.

Comment: makes sense! as a follow up, would you say it make sense to use both Optional + Computed vs just Optional attribute when developing with old SDK?

Let's say there's a string attribute and the use case is even if there's an echo endpoint (returns response.foo="hello" if request.spec.foo="hello" and response.foo = unset / "" for request.spec.foo=unset / "") d.Get() will still return "" for both null / "" so using "" over null would help to avoid confusing state drifts for `foo = null vs foo=""` (I guess it still might be possible to avoid null / "" but one missed if can damage the tf state).

Comment: Let me know if I should create a separate question instead.

Comment: created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850925/shall-i-set-both-computed-and-optional-vs-just-optional-for-a-string-attribute-i

Comment: "SDKv2 was designed for Terraform v0.11  and earlier" Not to nitpick, but I believe in 0.11 and earlier we used the Terraform core package directly. SDKv1 was synced with 0.12, and then SDKv2 followed soon thereafter around 0.14.

Comment: Yes, if you want to be pedantic  I did skip some steps here, but the fact remains that the vast majority of the code in SDKv2 is the same as the code that was originally in various packages in the Terraform repository; it moved out there only so that it could evolve independently of Terraform itself. Despite the timing of those, the design of the code in that repository dates from long before Terraform v0.12 was even planned.

Comment: The SDKv2 repository contains [forks of portions of Terraform v0.11](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/tree/466cbe533ef9ee5c61b6e0208cc33365944db8a9/terraform) in order to allow it to keep working in spite of those codepaths no longer being present in modern Terraform.