# Shall I use d.Set() for a computer attribute?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm adding a new resource to Terraform Provider using Terraform SDKv2 (can't use the new Terraform Plugin).

One of new resource's attributes is the following:

```
"foo_enabled": {
  Type:     schema.TypeBool,
  // Computed: true,
  Optional: true,
  Default:  false,
},
```

I absolutely want this attribute to be optional and have a default value since it's not very important and only applicable for advanced users.

In my code, I only use `d.Get("foo_enabled")` in `resourceCreate()` and that's it. However when I started testing it, I figured if I don't set it to any value in Terraform configuration, it's being saved as `foo_enabled = null` in TF state file, when I set it to false / true in Terraform configuration, then it's being saved as `foo_enabled = false / true` (not 100% sure but I think it's accurate, don't remember what the value is after importing -- maybe it's false / true for create but null after importing).

To make things worse, I run into an issue with testing:

```
  {
    // https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/resources/import.html
    ResourceName:      ...,
    ImportState:       true,
    ImportStateVerify: true,
},
```

It used to work but now `ImportStateVerify` fails with actual: null, expected: true / false.

The main point is I'd rather have it as explicit `true / false` in any scenario to avoid drifts null -> false, or false -> null.

So I'm thinking about setting it in `resourceRead()` like

```
foo := d.Get("foo_enabled").(bool)
d.Set("foo_enabled", foo)
```

and marking a resource as `Computed` to allow these `d.Set()` calls. Is it a reasonable idea?

Related: [Shall I set an empty string computed string attribute for Terraform resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849664/shall-i-set-an-empty-string-computed-string-attribute-for-terraform-resource/71850659#71850659)

Comment: Just to clarify: the decision around whether to set the `Computed` attribute here derives from your need for a workaround for some behavioral compatibility issue between SDKv2 and the provider's API, and not whether it is actually computed or not. Is that correct? If so, then I believe as long as you always remember to `.Set()` at the end of the CRUD functions, then you should be fine. Whether or not there is a better solution is honestly beyond me, and maybe if "backwards Rocksteady" saw this question you could have a good answer.

Comment: If so, then I believe as long as you always remember to .Set() at the end of the CRUD functions, then you should be fine. -- is this a suggestion for using together with Computed: True or without it? I'd approve this comment as an answer btw.

Comment: For `Computed: true`.